# Problem adding and deleting objects from python class

Tags: python, oop

Please can someone help me to fix the code, I want to create a school class and create an object. After that, I want to use the join function to add students ( if a student exists it will not add it and it will show a message, and if not exists it will add the student), same as the leave function (it will delete from the list only if exists). and finally, the show_all function will display all the values in the list. I think the structure of the code is wrong, so please can someone help me

```html
class School:
    
    def __init__(self):
        print("A class has opened!")

    def join(self, student):
        self.student = student
        if self.student not in my_school:
            print(self.student +" is a new member of the school!")
        
        else:
            print("We already have "+ self.student +".")
        
    def leave(self):
        if self.student in my_school:
            del self.student
        
        else:
            print("No such student")
            
        
    def show_all(self):
        print(my_school)

# create new object in class
my_school = School() 

# add the student if not exists only
my_school.join('Sarah') 
# delete if exists
my_school.leave("Noor")
# show all the list
my_school.show_all()
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several errors:

1. When you call `join` (a bad method name, because it already exists) you reassign the student to single variable.
2. In leave you reference the instance witch is not possible because it doesn't jet exist.

Here is some code:

```
class School:
    
    def __init__(self):
        print("An instance of School was created!")
        self.students = []

    def join(self, student):
        if student not in self.students:
            self.students.append(student)
            print(student + " is a new member of the school!")
        else:
            print("We already have "+ student +".")
        
    def leave(self, student):
        if student in self.students:
            self.students.remove(student)
        else:
            print("No such student")
            
    def show_all(self):
        print(self.students)

# create new object in class
my_school = School() 

# add the student if not in students
my_school.join("Sarah")

# delete the student if in the students list
my_school.leave("Noor")

# print the students
my_school.show_all()
```

This is by no means good code, but comes close to what you wanted to achieve.